# How to group keys from a nested object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, grouping, nested-object

Hya

Suppose we have a dynamic object like so:

```json
[
    {
        "object": "block",
        "id": "089cd0d8-ccbf-4e9e-97a6",
        "parent": {
            "type": "page_id",
            "page_id": "d4b96daf-47a3-4a04-b200"
        },
        "type": "child_database",
        "child_database": {
            "title": "Hero"
        }
    },
    {
        "object": "page",
        "id": "d3022361-96d2-4e15-999e",
        "parent": {
            "type": "database_id",
            "database_id": "089cd0d8-ccbf-4e9e-97a6"
        },
    },
    {
        "object": "block",
        "id": "a0cba166-1787-4e30-8cc3",
        "parent": {
            "type": "page_id",
            "page_id": "d3022361-96d2-4e15-999e"
        },
        "type": "heading_1",
        "heading_1": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": {
                        "content": "Introduction",
                        "link": null
                    },
                    "plain_text": "Introduction",
                    "href": null
                }
            ],
        }
    },
    {
        "object": "block",
        "id": "dbfdd892-8c04-4de3-bf0e",
        "parent": {
            "type": "page_id",
            "page_id": "d3022361-96d2-4e15-999e"
        },
        "type": "heading_2",
        "heading_2": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": {
                        "content": "This is introduction section",
                        "link": null
                    },
                    "plain_text": "This is introduction section",
                    "href": null
                }
            ],
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to reconstruct this object by grouping them based on parent-child like relationship. Since every object has `"parent"` prop.

The desired result should be like so, where the elements that share the same parent are grouped under `child` array.

```json
{
  "d4b96daf-47a3-4a04-b200": {
    "object": "block",
    "id": "089cd0d8-ccbf-4e9e-97a6",
    "type": "child_database",
    "child": [{
      "d3022361-96d2-4e15-999e": {
        "object": "page",
        "child": [{
            "a0cba166-1787-4e30-8cc3": {
              "object": "block",
              "type": "heading_1",
              "heading_1": {
                "rich_text": [{
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": {
                    "content": "Introduction",
                    "link": null
                  },
                  "plain_text": "Introduction",
                  "href": null
                }]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "dbfdd892-8c04-4de3-bf0e": {
              "object": "block",
              "type": "heading_1",
              "heading_2": {
                "rich_text": [{
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": {
                    "content": "This is introduction section",
                    "link": null
                  },
                  "plain_text": "This is introduction section",
                  "href": null
                }]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

## Current workaround

```js
/**
 * Generator that traverses through nested object
 */
function* traverse(xs: any[] = []): any {
  for (let x of xs) {
    yield x
    yield* traverse(x.child || [])
  }
}

/**
 * If the property exists in the nested object, then return node
 */
const deepFind = (block: any, pred: any) => (obj: any) => {
  for (let node of traverse([obj])) {
    if (pred(node)) {
      return node
    }
  }
}

const findById = (block: any) => (obj: any) => deepFind(block, (o: any) => o[block.id])(obj)

export default async function group(pages: Page[]) {
  // stuck here  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this linearly: create a Map `id=>object`, iterate the list,  if the parent is already on the map, add your object to the parent.child, otherwise create a placeholder object with the parent's id.

```
let m = new Map()

for (let obj of data) {
    let dummy = {id: 'dummy', child: []}
    
    let oid = obj.id
    m.set(oid, {...dummy, ...obj, ...m.get(oid)})

    let pid = obj.parent.page_id // or whatever depending on type

    m.set(pid, m.get(pid) ?? dummy)
    m.get(pid).child.push(obj)
}
```

In the end, the `m.values()` will contain a flat list of objects with `child` arrays properly populated.